# Render google font to svg path path but wrap as a promise

Tags: angular

I have the following script, which performs an async operation. I would like to wrap it in a promise, but I am not ssure how.

```
  static renderGoogleFontToSvgPath(): Promise<string> {
    const url = 'http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/quicksand/v21/6xK-dSZaM9iE8KbpRA_LJ3z8mH9BOJvgkKEo18G0wx40QDw.ttf';
    const text = 'hello';
    const size = 14;
    const union = false;
    const bezierAccuracy = 0;
    let svg = null;
    opentype.load(url, (err, font) => {
      const textModel = new makerjs.models.Text(font, text, size, union, false, bezierAccuracy);
      svg = makerjs.exporter.toSVG(textModel);
      // produces code here
      console.log(svg)
    });
    // null
    return svg;
  }
```

As when I call it here, the result is null.

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    const font = BuilderSidebarTextService.renderGoogleFontToSvgPath();
    console.log(font);
 }
```

How do I fix it in a Angular compatible way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time the function returns `svg` variable's value is null because it is set in an async function. So you need to return a `Promise`.

```
 static renderGoogleFontToSvgPath(): Promise<string> {
    const url = 'http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/quicksand/v21/6xK-dSZaM9iE8KbpRA_LJ3z8mH9BOJvgkKEo18G0wx40QDw.ttf';
    const text = 'hello';
    const size = 14;
    const union = false;
    const bezierAccuracy = 0;
    let svg = null;
    return new Promise(resolve => {
    opentype.load(url, (err, font) => {
      const textModel = new makerjs.models.Text(font, text, size, union, false, bezierAccuracy);
      svg = makerjs.exporter.toSVG(textModel);
      // produces code here
      resolve(svg);
    });
  });
 }
```

> And use it like below :

```
async ngOnInit(): void {
    const font = await BuilderSidebarTextService.renderGoogleFontToSvgPath();
    console.log(font);
 }
```